# Circular imageview border is not showing

Tags: android

I am using circular image view to show profile image in my app.

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

I am trying to get white border around image but unable to get.
Below is my code.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"/>
```

Someone please let me know how can I get desired layout.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is by design -- if no image is set, the borders are not drawn. Try to set an image or fill the view with a color:

```
android:src="@color/red"
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see any problem with your code. Try to set the image as src. Below is my code and works fine in my code.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_width= "100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:civ_border_width="3dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size20"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@mipmap/user_new"
    />
```

Comment: Yeah actually I was not adding src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just closed and opened again the xml tab and the border appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try these attributes:

```
app:border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:border_width="2dp"
app:border="true"
```